# Signs in XML can't be copied

Tags: android, xml

I am having some problems with symbols on one android application.

Does any one know where I can find Alt code? For example I need to put  **∪** sing or similar ones in **.xml** file in *string*. If i try to pasted copied only square with question mark inside appears. So this makes a problem, because I need a lot of those similar signs and it's sometimes hard to find Alt code on the Google...

I would be pleased if any one could help me to solve this and give some other options or opportunities how to make those signs.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

For that symbols you can use their encoded on XML.
For example the [union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) will be `&#8746;`